# Error when calculating Gini coefficient with user-defined function in ddply

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, plyr

I am trying to use ddply to generate the Gini coefficients of several groups of observations. My data looks something like this: (this is obviously artificial)

```
 Group  Name Month       Wage
 A      Alice January     0
 A     Alice February    300
 A     Alice February    400
 B     Alice March       500
 B     Bob   January     1000
 B     Bob   January     2500
```

I want to get the Gini coefficients of the wages, grouped by group, name, and month. Right now, I have the below code. It uses a user-defined function for doing the calculation because I needed to modify the data a little before sending it to gini. There's also a user-defined gini function that I found [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-June/133875.html), because the standard ineq function wasn't working correctly for me.

```
#add up to 5 0's if there are not enough observations
fakeinflate <- function(x) 
{
  toadd <- 5 - length(x[[1]])
  add <- rep(0, toadd)
  togin <- c(x$wage, add)
  g <- ineq(togin)
  return(g)
}

#calculate the Gini coefficient
gini <- function(x, unbiased = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE){
  if (!is.numeric(x)){
    warning("'x' is not numeric; returning NA")
    return(NA)
  }
  if (!na.rm && any(na.ind <- is.na(x)))
    stop("'x' contain NAs")
  if (na.rm)
    x <- x[!na.ind]
  n <- length(x)
  mu <- mean(x)
  N <- if (unbiased) n * (n - 1) else n * n
  ox <- x[order(x)]
  dsum <- drop(crossprod(2 * 1:n - n - 1,  ox))
  dsum / (mu * N)
}

#aggregate with ddply
allginis <- ddply(allwagesdf, c("Group", "Name"), fakeinflate)
```

When I run this, I get the following error: 'Error: invalid 'times' argument'. I have tried debugging and my function seems to be running fine - the error is thrown in ddply. Does anyone know what this means and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems is in `fakeInflate`. `toadd` can become negative when the vector has more than 5 elements. Use this instead:

```
toadd <- max(0, 5 - length(x[[1]]))
```

Comment: I was able to verify your solution, +1

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Silly mistake, but I didn't think to make that function more robust because I was sure that there would never be more than 5. Lesson learned.